# Reask for declined permissions facebook rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app, which can share photos to facebook. When user shares photos for the first time, opens popup with permissions on facebook. User can decline permissions and then app will fail and facebook popup with permissions will never be shown again. How can i ask for permissions again if they were declined? 
I use koala gem to implement sharing. Here i check for permissions but don't know how to force facebook popup visible again

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
    permissions = @graph.get_connections('me','permissions')
    @has_wallpost_permission = permissions[0]['user_photos'].to_i == 1 ? true : false
```

Comment: To re-ask for a previously declined permission, the FB login dialog has to be called with additional parameter `auth_type=rerequest`. (But don’t ask me how to do that with your SKD, I don’t know – check its docs.)

Comment: Here is my workaround: I am checking if all permissions are confirmed and if not, delete all of them and facebook asks all permissions again.